# can't access parental data context (meteor/blaze)

Tags: templates, meteor, pug, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm trying to figure out how to use [dynamic templates](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/) correctly in my meteor application.

First, I have a set of templates to be inserted dynamically, e.g. `moduleSearch`, which contains a search form:

```
template(name='moduleSearch') 
    input(placeholder='search', type='text')
```

My `header` template looks as follow:

```
template(name='header')
    each modules
      li
        +UI.dynamic template=this data=objectsList
```

Each of the `yield` templates includes the header template with a dynamically changing set of modules, depending on the current `yield` template. E.g. My `objectsList` template..

```
template(name='objectsList')
  +UI.dynamic template='headerYield' data=modules
```

..includes the `moduleSearch` template:

```
Template.objectsList.helpers({

  modules: function() {
    return ['moduleSearch'];
  }
```

All the templates are displayed properly, as expected. The `moduleSearch` template contains a search form, to **query the collection items at the `objectsList` template**, however, it **doesn't work**. How can I get the parental context (access `objectList`'s  data & helper functions from `moduleSearch`)?

PS - When I copy-paste the content of the `moduleSearch` template into the `objectsList` template, the search feature works, data is being filtered reactively in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the datacontext into the helper

```
{{> mysubtemplate parentdatacontext=datacontext}}
```

See more here: http://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#name-data-contexts